# Boundedness of convex function with given property of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, contest-math

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and convex on domain. It's given also that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $|f'(n^2)|≥\frac{1}{n^2}$. Prove that $f$ is unbounded.

I suppose  that $f$ is bounded and hence I show $f$ must be decreasing and has horizontal asymptote below. I don't   have any idea how to use a hypothese about $|f'(n^2)| $and show a contradiction. I would be grateful for any hint, I don't want a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact: the derivative of a convex function is increasing.

Consider two cases:

1. $f'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$, and
2. $f'(x)>0$ for some $x>0$.

In both cases, you can write
$$
f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^bf'(x)\,dx,
$$
and $f'(x)$ between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for all large enough $n$ have the same sign, and can be estimated via $f'(n^2)$, and, in turn, via $\frac{1}{n^2}$. It will give at the end the comparison series
$$
\sum_n\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2}=\sum_n\frac{2n+1}{n^2},
$$
which is divergent.